# Why is broccoli-asset-rev fingerprinting my files differently on different servers?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I am getting different hashes running the same build process with the same `package.json` using the same git hash on different machines.

My build process that builds my `dist` is `ember build --environment production`.

When run locally, I get a fingerprint like: `61d20923c56bef5632711ada4bb76246`.

When run on my CI server, I get a fingerprint like: `c45ef7f3dbb98441099e10e59e09abef`.

When run on my Heroku server, I get a fingerprint like: `0485d770eb6209fa1387242e0e889d5f`.

**This is a problem because I push my assets to S3 with `grunt` and then expect that fingerprint to be the same.**

This same build process was working two weeks ago for me, so I can't imagine what changed.

I'm on `npm 2.1.14`, `node 0.10.35`, `ember-cli 0.1.15` and `broccoli-asset-rev ^2.0.0`.

Comment: The only commit |I can see that could affect this was back in 2014: https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev/commit/83cf41b95e39dc91ecae4d9acaf3366a7492c439

Comment: @iwayneo yeah and I would have seen that before now. I pushed 13 days ago to production and had no issues.